# Python - SQLite For Loop OperationalError

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've been given a messy Excel file that I am trying to transfer into tidied SQL tables. I am building a Python program to do the transfer. There is a list of names, some of which are repeated. I've already gotten the column with all the names into a list of tuples like:

```py
[(John Christopher, ), (Elizabeth Smith, ), (etc, )]
```

I've built an SQL table called Players and have an empty column named "id". I'm trying to iterate through this list and assign a unique id to each player in the Table and then also delete the duplicate names in my table.

However I keep getting this error:

```
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Players SET id = "+str(id)+" WHERE name = "+str(item[0]))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Christopher": syntax error
```

What is my issue?

Here is the code:

```py
import sqlite3

player_list_start = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM Players")
saved_list = player_list_start.fetchall()

# number id should start on
id = 1

# list of players to keep track if they are already in the table
names = []

for item in saved_list:
    if item[0] not in names:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE Players SET id = "+str(id)+" WHERE name = "+str(item[0]))
        connection.commit()
        names.append(item[0])
        id += 1
    else:
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Players WHERE name = "+str(item[0])+" AND id = NULL")
        connection.commit()
```

Comment: Really need a minimum example for this - can you hardcode values for `saved_list` and add creating the database and cursor to your code.

Comment: The error that you are facing is from a syntax error in the SQL itself. What you need to do is print out the SQL statement that you are producing, and see if there are any errors. Try pasting the code into a SQL terminal and see what happens.

Comment: Try this: `cursor.execute("UPDATE Players SET id = ? WHERE name = ?", (id, item[0]))`

Comment: If your SQLite version supports it, you could use a `row_number` solution to do it all in one shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely says `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Christopher": syntax error` .

The following line will generate syntactically wrong SQL statement because it does not quote strings (especially including spaces).

```py
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Players WHERE name = "+str(item[0])+" AND id = NULL")
```

Use

```py
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Players WHERE name = '"+str(item[0])+"' AND id = NULL")
```

or

```py
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Players WHERE name = ? AND id = NULL", (str(item[0]),))
```